# cocos2dx sdkbox: How to turn personalized advertisements off for GDPR

Tags: admob, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using Admob + sdkbox + cocos2dx for ads. The official [documentation](http://docs.sdkbox.com/en/plugins/admob/v3-cpp/) has a function setGDPR(bool). But its not explained I should set it true or false for non-personalized-ads.

For EU users for non-personalized Ads should I do:

```
sdkbox::PluginUnityAds::setGDPR(true);
```

OR

```
sdkbox::PluginUnityAds::setGDPR(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void setGDPR ( bool enabled ) ;
```

According to your given documentation link

```
set GDPR.  true : For non-personalized ads, 
           false: For personalized ads.
```